# J2SE interfaces specifications and implementations of those interfaces

Tags: java, interface, java-7

I was looking at rt.jar for some reasons and there i saw some packages like java.sql.* among others.

In a typical jdbc program we write (for Connection class, for example):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

As per the docs, java.sql.Connection is interface, not concrete implementation, and java.sql.Connection is in rt.jar.

When we write jdbc program, we need jdbc drivers, and from what i read jdbc drivers implement interfaces (e.g. java.sql.Connection).

So when we write in typical java program: (and load the jdbc drivers)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

--> does java.sql.Connection come from rt.jar or from the driver classes.

From what i guess, in this case java.sql.Connection has to come from rt.jar (as interface), and actual implementation comes from driver classes.

If my assumption is correct, in general do we need to include the jar's which have interface definitions in order to include the import.

For example, consider this situation:

```
package com.vipin.myinterface;

public interface Interface1 {
      public void print();
}
```

And if we package above interface as interface1.jar.

Suppose Concrete1.java implements this interface:

```
package com.vipin.concrete1;
    public class Concrete1 implements Interface1 {

         public void print () {
               //code
         }
   }
```

And this packaged in jar --> concrete1.jar.

Now, suppose i am writing an application which uses print() method, so do i need to include both these jar's?

Comment: @bayou.io why don't you write an answer?

Comment: @Würgspaß - coz I'm lazy? :)

Comment: @bayou.io or maybe because you cannot give a proper explanation on the subject.

Comment: The proper explanation was given in the question.

Comment: @Würgspaß I do not see such proper explanation, in fact I just see two question: *how this is done?* and *can I do it as easily as it looks like?*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - so... coz I'm stupid? :) That is always true.

Comment: @bayou.io that's not what I've said. You can know how something works but maybe have problems on explain this to other people. That doesn't make you stupid, just have difficult to express yourself :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - if I cannot express myself, for all practical purposes I'm stupid to outside observers.

Comment: @bayou.io whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case for `java.sql.Connection` is that the driver provides the implementation classes for this and other interfaces like `java.sql.Statement`, `java.sql.ResultSet`, and on. All the *magic* of binding the interface to the proper class implementation happens in the method [`DriverManager#getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-), which calls an internal method `private static Connection getConnection(String url, java.util.Properties info, Class<?> caller) throws SQLException` that will initialize the proper instance of `java.sql.Connection`.

Of course, you can use a similar approach in your code that will use reflection to:

- Find the proper implementation of the interface
- If there's a proper implementation, create an instance of this class.
- Return the instance of this class once initialized and running.
- Throw proper exception(s) if the class cannot be found or if it has any initialization issue.

Please do not think that just creating a jar containing the interfaces and another containing the implementation classes of this interfaces will automatically wire up on the fly for you, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Actually you can also call DriverManager#getDriver and then call Driver#connect, so if you have to reconnect you already have the right implementation. Also, you could have said that each driver implementation have a method acceptsURL(...), so that the DriverManager only has to ask every implementation and get the one that does accept the url.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope my point here is: you cannot just create an interface and an implementation and expect that Java loads the implementation for you and initialize your interface on the fly. You have to do it somehow, and `Driver#getConnection` is not an exception to this rule.